# Issue getting a payment form to work

Tags: php, payment

I've been assisting a friend to help him fix his payment form on his website, however after fixing a few database errors, there is now an error that I just can't seem to do anything about. The errors is as shows:

> Notice: Undefined variable: strEPDQ in
>   /home/sites/mulgas.co.uk/public_html/payments.php on line 274

Now after looking at the code, I can't see the issue **Since there is a lot of code, I've cut it down to the relevant segment**:

```
    #for each line in the response check for the presence of the string 'epdqdata'
#this line contains the encrypted string
$response_line_count=count($response_lines);
for ($i=0;$i<$response_line_count;$i++){
    if (preg_match('/epdqdata/',$response_lines[$i])){
        $strEPDQ=$response_lines[$i];
    }
}
?>
```

If you need anymore information, I'll provide it

Comment: just set `$strEPDQ = '' ;` on the top of `count()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
#for each line in the response check for the presence of the string 'epdqdata'
#this line contains the encrypted string
$strEPDQ = '';
$response_line_count=count($response_lines);
for ($i=0;$i<$response_line_count;$i++){
    if (preg_match('/epdqdata/',$response_lines[$i])){
        $strEPDQ=$response_lines[$i];
    }
}
?>
```

It's just a notice, nothing very serious. :-)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, however, I placed that in over the old code, and I'm still getting the same undefined variable notice

Comment: And `$strEPDQ` isn't used anywhere else?

Comment: It's used one other place, however that's just the call up which is causing the notice: <?php print $strEPDQ; ?> a little further down

Comment: 100 % sure it's these lines of code that the error refers to?

Comment: Nope, nowhere before that section of code & yeah, that's what the line's referring to, I'll double check now

Comment: Weird. Try setting `$strEPDQ = '';` in the very beginning of the document.

Comment: Line 274 is:       <FORM action="https://secure2.epdq.co.uk/cgi-bin/CcxBarclaysEpdq.e" method="POST">
            <div align="left"><?php print $strEPDQ; ?>

However, that's just calling up the string

Comment: Do this: `<?php print isset($strEPDQ) ? $strEPDQ : ''; ?>`

Comment: Wohoo! No problem :-)